htaccess file for child_laravel project in existing laravel project
i have two laravel projects
rootlaravelproject
than in rootlaravelproject i have another laravel project
i was unable to access my sub_laravel_project than i updated .htaccess file inside sub_laravel_project like below
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myrootdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myrootdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myrootdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.myrootdomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

now i am able to access sub_laravel_project but my assets are not working
when i try follwoing i am able to access assets
https://sub_laravel_project_domain.com/public/images/logo.png
but withoud public i am unable to access i think i have to update htaccess pelase help thanks
tried answers on stackoverflow but no luck

You've set your RewriteBase to /subdirectory which does not exist in your directory tree. Changing your RewriteBase to /public will result in the requests being rewritten relative to this directory.

thansks for answering
tried but still same
